# Compile error program socket in java

Tags: java, sockets

I've begun learning socket programming in Java. I have copied code from tutorialspoint.com and run it in Eclipse. But the compiler gives me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

This is my code:

```java
//File Name GreetingClient.java

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String serverName = args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port "
                    + port);
            Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
            System.out.println("Just connected to "
                    + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

            out.writeUTF("Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
            InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
            System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Post your code.. An `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` is an easy one. Occurs when you try to access an array index that doesn't exist. For example, `String[] myArray = new String[1]` has 1 index, `myArray[0]`. If we tried accessing `myArray[5]`, the error would occur

Comment: This is my code: http://ideone.com/Ub5Ui5 . I know exception...

Comment: Seems as if you're trying to access the command line arguments, but didn't specify any. `args[1]` or even `args[0]` could throw the error if you don't specify command line arguments. If running in Eclipse, right click your project, click `Run As... > Run Configurations`, you'll stumble across where you can enter the arguments

Comment: Do you supply `args` at all?  How do you run the program?

Comment: By the way, this is a runtime exception, which is different from an `error` or a compiler problem.

Comment: Basically, you need to supply the server name as an argument when you run the program.

Comment: I try to click Run as. But it isn't change.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of your code, you must be forgetting to specify command-line arguments. The `String[] args` contains the arguments, and if you don't specify any, the array won't have a size. Accessing it when it had no size gives you the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

To fix this, simply specify command-line arguments when you run your application. If running from a command prompt, you specify it after typing in `java MyClass`. In Eclipse, you'd specify them in your project's run configuration.

For your application, you need 2 arguments. The first one should be the hostname of the server you're connecting to, and the second one is the port it's binded to.

Also, this is a run time exception, not a compile time error.

Answer (score -2):

In your case,

```
public static void main(String[] args) { // parameter is an array
    // which is arguments which you pass when you run the app
    // either through console from where you are running your java file
    // or from setting in IDE
}
```

what it does is it takes all arguments that you provide in console separated by space and puts it into array and passes as parameter to main function.

if you are not passing anything, you will get error

```
// here you should have args[0] and args[1] , 
// meaning you should have args array with 2 elements in it. 
    String serverName = args[0];
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
// you will get error if array doesnot contain anything ar just 1 element.
```

from your command line, run this after you compile java code

```
java javaFileClassName arg1 arg2
```

If you are running it from eclipse, Go to

```
Run > Arguments tab > type your all arguments there
```

refer to this if you are using 
command line 
[Providing command line arguments](http://www.javatpoint.com/command-line-argument)

Eclipse
[Using Command line arguments in eclipse](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/eclipseCommLineArgs.html)

Comment: How to fix it the program run?

Comment: So long as the indexing is in bounds of the array, you'll still get a value back - it'll just be the initial value for that data type.  So, for primitives, you'll get 0 back; for objects, you'll get `null`.  You *won't* get an AIOOBE for that.